# Page goes up after pressing button PHP

Tags: php, calendar

I used a calendar from the internet which uses PHP. It has buttons like "next" and "prev", and when I press one of them it takes me to the top of the page. How can I fix that?

This is the code where I create the calendar:

```
    return
        '<div class="header">'.
            '<a class="prev" href="'.$this->naviHref.'?
            month='.sprintf('%02d',$preMonth).'&year='.$preYear.'">Prev</a>'.
           '<span class="title">'.date('Y M',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-1')).'</span>'.
           '<a class="next" href="'.$this->naviHref.'?month='.sprintf("%02d", $nextMonth).'&year='.$nextYear.'">Next</a>'.
        '</div>';
    }
```

And here calendar.php

https://ideone.com/SkECOp

Comment: This is a little Broad! Can you not focus in on where you think the problem may lie, just to save us all having to bench test all this code

Comment: I focused it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies not in your updated code, but in assigning `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to `naviHref` in the constructor.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

Read the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` value in the script where you create the `Calendar`instance and pass that value as argument to the `Calendar` constructor. In which it will be assigned to `naviHref`.

Also, the first two lines inside `show()` are raising notices

```
$year == null;
$month == null;
```

Change them to

```
$year = null;
$month = null;
```

**Edit**:

In order to use your calender component, you have to create an instance of it, an object of `Calendar` type, like this:

```
$calendar = new Calendar();
```

This takes place in a php file.

But before doing this step, assign the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to a variable. Like this:

```
$naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

And after that create your object of type `Calendar`, by passing it the variable, as argument. Like this:

```
$calendar = new Calendar($naviHref);
```

So, in the end you will have the following code in your php page:

```
$naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$calendar = new Calendar($naviHref);

echo $calendar->show();
```

After this, go to the `Calendar` constructor and change it like this:

```
public function __construct($naviHref) {
    $this->naviHref = $naviHref;
}
```

This way you injected the variable $naviHref into your object of class `Calendar`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don`t understand what should I do, because I`m new in PHP language. Could you please explain again?

Comment: @Sergiu, can you please give us then some more information about the file in which you create the object? Do you have some javascript in that page? Or maybe a HTML form, or something like that? Please post them by reediting your question, not in comments. This way can all of us see them.

Comment: @Sergiu Some code around the rows where you create the `Calendar` would be very helpful. Or maybe the whole page, if it doesn't bother you?

Comment: I have a form below. Can it affect the calendar?

Comment: @SergiuTritean Sorry, but we need a lot more :-)

Comment: @SergiuTritean Yes it's possible.

Comment: I dont want to hide the code, but I showed you the PHP file and you said it`s too much. Should I post it again? Or the form?

Comment: @SergiuTritean No, I personally didn't said that. I tooked your class and tested it in my php environment. In the code of your class as I studied it, I didn't find any place more, that should arrise some doubts. That's why I think, that the problem lies in some other place. And the first one to think of would be, at least as first step, the calling php file.

Comment: @SergiuTritean Oh, sorry: yes, the file with the form in it would be the one to show.

Comment: @SergiuTritean Yes, thanks. I'm testing it right now.

Comment: @SergiuTritean In this file I can't find nothing related to the Calendar. We now have the context in which Calendar is supposed to be created, but we can't make any correlations without knowing where in this context your calender lies.

Comment: What should I give you now?

Comment: @SergiuTritean You gave me a "Contact" page. Where is Calendar use/implemented in it? Am I missing something?

Comment: @SergiuTritean In the code of your question I see something about "evenimente". Should this be part of the "contact" page?

Comment: @SergiuTritean Got it.

Comment: Evenimente is where the calendar is located. "Contact" Page is the form. I didnt used the calendar in the form, at least that`s what I know :))

Comment: @SergiuTritean Can you please post the Evenimente page? That's what it's all about.

Comment: @SergiuTritean are you trying to say that Evenimente is a page, Contact is another, and both of them are embedded into another one, somehow? If that's the case, then we just made a big step further. That third file we need also.

Comment: @SergiuTritean Yes, now we have it: both of them, Evenimente and Contact are just parts of a main page. Right? Than we need this page. We need ALL pieces in order to find the needle in the haystack :-)

Comment: So you want the whole page?

Comment: @SergiuTritean Yes I need it.

Comment: @SergiuTritean Yes, that's the one. Tell me please if in the header of this file are any javascripts or javascript inclusions defined? Because the file is incomplete in regard of its header.

Comment: @aendreerei No javascript includes it

Comment: @SergiuTritean Ok .

Comment: @SergiuTritean When you go with the mouse over Prev or Next button in Calendar, what link is displayed in the tooltip?  Please send me that piece of text. Feel free to change the letters, but I need to know the structure of that url.

Comment: index.php?month=06&year=2017. It shows which month and year is next

Comment: @SergiuTritean Hi. I was looking at your code. Yes, when you navigate through your calender you are taken to the top of the page. But not because there is something wrong with your code. The source lies indeed in the "prev" and "next" buttons. Actually in the way in which they are triggering the changes. They are anchors, implemented with the default behavior. So, when you click them, you are redirected to the same page in which the calender is used. Hence making the whole page to reload and inevitable producing the scroll-to-top effect. I must admit, I overlooked the evidence. Sorry for that.

Comment: @SergiuTritean In order to effectively avoid such a behavior you should take in consideration the use of jQuery plugins. Such components are provided, for example, by **[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com)**. As a note: both, jQuery and jQuery UI are developed and maintained by the same foundation. jQuery UI provides a great collection of widgets, themes, effects, etc. They have a "Datepicker Widget" too. You'll like it.

Comment: @SergiuTritean Oh, hi. No, their is no problem per se. The way in which your component works is "the problem" :-)

Comment: @SergiuTritean It seems that your code contains also some private infos. I recommend you to delete the links to your files from the question and comments and just reinsert the initial, "focused" version of your code. Good luck with your projects!

Comment: @aendreei Ok, I understand :) Thank you very much again